# Unexpected delay on multicore GPUs /iPhone5 & iPad3 >/

Tags: iphone, ios, synchronization, gpu, delay

Testing our product for the last 3 months I can conclude there is some behaviour change in the  iOS for the MULTY GPU devices. 
The - (void)layoutSubviews { } is called about 5 to 15 sec later when the view is prebuilt offscreen.
When changing UIImageView.image the same latency occurs.

Has anyone handled this issue yet? Is it GPU related indeed?

Comment: 5-15sec is a huge latency... do you make your changes on background thread by any chance?

Comment: there is nothing in background for this exact part of the interface building.
I am just arranging many small images and building deep view hierarchy and on the iPad Retina (3) and the iPhone 5 the layoutSubviews is not called for more than 7 sec after the interface is already presented and functional. Sometimes when you press the buttons their images are updated, and after a few seconds all other images are updated without user interaction /at once/.

I suppose it is some GPU threading. Is there any way to force single threading in the GPU?